# Is this function differentiable w.r.t. a variable in an indicator?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have

$$y^i = x^i - \alpha \sum_{j \epsilon N} (x^j - x^i) I_{x^i \lt x^j} - \beta \sum_{j \epsilon N} (x^i - x^j) I_{x^i \ge x^j}$$

where N = {1, 2, ..., n}, and $I_{x^i \lt x^j}$ is 1 when $x^i \lt x^j$ and 0 otherwise.

It appears to be continuous and smooth because the subtraction of $x^i$ and $x^j$ equals zero as an $x^j$ passes from being a part of one sum to another, but can this function be differentiated with respect to $x^i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at a simpler example, $f(x)=I_{x<0}$. Clearly $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ since it isn't even continuous at $0$. Now what about $f(x)=x I_{x<0}$? Now it's continuous at $0$, but the left derivative is $+1$ and the right derivative is $0$, so it's not differentiable. In general we can take $f(x)=g(x)I_{x<0}$ and if $g$ is differentiable with $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, then the left and right derivatives will be equal, so $f$ will be differentiable at $0$. E.g. $f(x)=x^2 I_{x<0}$ would be differentiable everywhere.

We can do a similar analysis on your function. Fix $i$. For points $x$ where we do not have $x^j=x^i$ for any $j$, we will have no trouble. But, if $x^j=x^i$ for some $j$, unless $\alpha=-\beta$, when checking to see if $\partial_j y^i$ exists at $x$, we will be in a situation that looks like $xI_{x<0}$ near $0$.

Can you use these observation to resolve your questions?

This might also help you:

**Theorem** If $f$'s partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a ball, then $f$ is differentiable in that ball.

(Note: theorem can be significantly generalized by requiring much weaker hypotheses)

Comment: Ok - so, if I alter the function to be $$y^i = x^i - \alpha \sum_{j \epsilon N} (x^j - x^i)^2 I_{x^i \lt x^j} - \beta \sum_{j \epsilon N} (x^i - x^j)^2 I_{x^i \ge x^j}$$, there's a right derivative like $1 - 2 \alpha (x^i - x^j)$ and a left derivative like $1 + 2 \beta (x^j - x^i)$.  Then as $x^i$ nears $x^j$ we have equal derivatives on both sides, and differentiability?

Comment: That's essentially correct, but differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a little stronger than saying the partials exist. Since the terms each involve only two variables, it would be sufficient to show that the function $f(x,y) = (x-y)^2I_{x<y}$ is differentiable.

Comment: Hint: either use the theorem, or note that both $g(u) = u^2 I_{u<0}$ and $h(x,y) = y-x$ are differentiable so $f(x,y)=g(h(x,y))$ is too.